# make visual studio add all necessary when building release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

So I am working on an example project that displays video from a network stream.

The project is in C++.

After building the project in release, and trying to run the project on a different computer, I get errors on missing DLL files.

These DLL files are located within the installation location of Visual studio.
one example is msvcp140d.dll.

After copying all the missing files, I get a generic error with no specific file.

So:
Is there a way to tell visual studio to add all relevant files when building the project?

Comment: Do you know what visual studio "redistributables" are?

Comment: If the executable depends on `msvcp140d.dll`, then it's the debug build; that's what the last `d` stands for. Start by building a release build.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell visual studio to add all relevant files when
> building the project

Missing dlls at runtime is not a build issue.

Corresponding C++ redistributables need to be installed.

One solution is to use  static library. [/MT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170)